# Is the module $\mathbb Q[x]$ over $\mathbb Z[x]$ a Dedekind module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, ideals

Following the definition of Dedekind modules by Naoum and Al-Alwan (1996), a torsion-free module $M$ over an integral domain $D$ (with its field of fractions $K$) is called a Dedekind if every non-zero submodule $N$ of $M$ are invertible, that is $M=N^-N$ where $N^-=\{k\in K\ |\ kN\subseteq M\}$.

Originally I want to find a counterexample of Dedekind module $M[x]$ where $M$ is not a simple module. Currently I'm trying to check whether $\mathbb Q[x]$ over $\mathbb Z[x]$ is a Dedekind module or not. My guess is yes, since $\langle x,r\rangle$ is invertible for all $r\in\mathbb Z$. But I want to try to prove the invertibility for all non-zero submodules $N$.

Let $\{0\}\neq N\subsetneq\mathbb Q[x]$ a $\mathbb Z[x]$-submodule in $\mathbb Q[x]$ and $a(x)=a_0+a_1x+\ldots+a_px^p$ a non-zero element of $N$ with the least degree. It is clear that $N\subseteq N^-N$, so we want to prove that for all $m(x)\in M[x]\backslash N$, $m(x)\in M[x]\backslash N$. Note that for all $m(x)\in M[x]$, there exists $b(x),c(x)\in\mathbb Q[x]$ such that $m(x)=b(x)a(x)+c(x)$. Note that $b(x)a(x)\in\mathbb Q[x]N\subseteq N^-N$. How to prove that $c(x)\in N^-N$?

Thank you very much in advance.